# No valid aps-environment entitlement string found for application for Enterprise app

Tags: ios, xcode, meteor, apple-push-notifications

I am working on a meteor based iOS app. The client has the Enterprise Apple Developer account. I am sharing the app with client by uploading the ipa on my secure server(https) and providing him link to install the app for testing.

I am getting the push notification for development environment but when distributing the app using distribution certificates and provisioning profile I am getting this error in method "didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError".

I have also allowed the app for Push Notifications capability from Xcode.

I am using Xcode 9.3 and installing the app on iPad (9.7-inch) running 11.2.6.

I am extracting the ipa for Enterprise account for In-House distribution.

What I may be missing?

Answer (score -1):

> I have also allowed the app for Push Notifications capability from
>   Xcode.
>
> I am getting the push notification for development environment but
>   when distributing the app using distribution certificates and
>   provisioning profile I am getting this error in method
>   "didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError".

I guess that you have not regenerate a new provisioning profile after you add the push notification capability for the App ID in the developer portal.

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/

You should double check the certificate and provisioning profile you use to build the app contains push notification capability even when you enabled it in the Xcode.